# Javascript Search

Tags: javascript, facebook, search

I would like to add a search on name of people on my website.
The list of friends is already displayed on the page.

I love the way Facebook is doing this where you start typing a name and Facebook only displays your friends that match the query.

http://cl.ly/2t2V0v2Q103X2G1V080R
and
http://cl.ly/0R1j0B2n1s3y413i0a34

Any ideas on implementing this ?

Comment: I was a little unsure here, is this a Facebook apps. Or is this an outstanding site that has nothing to do with facebook API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that autocomplete is what you need. I don't know many jquery plugins. As it's pretty simple I'll go for custom code. If you have a lot of elements in the DOM, you need to create a cache for faster compute.

And you can get code and see a live demo here: http://xilinus.com/demos/instant-search-a-la-facebook/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to create an autocomplete facility, like the one facebook has. You have 3 choices in order to do that:

1. create your own autocompleter using javascript
2. use an existing implementation of this offered by a javascript framework like prototype/scriptaculous or jquery (eg [ajax.autocompleter](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/), [jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete))
3. search over the internet other implementations based on the facebook autocompleter style ([like this one](http://devthought.com/blog/projects-news/2008/01/textboxlist-fancy-facebook-like-dynamic-inputs/))

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery plugin to do this. jQuery is a js library that makes life nicer, and it supports plugins. The [tableFilter](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tableFilter) plugin does this, and with a minimal amount of code. If for some reason you don't like it or it doesn't work, there are plenty more available.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery Autocomplete-- but BE WARNED: if you search for "jquery autocomplete" you get the out-dated version.

DO NOT USE the first google result page -- this autocompelte has been deprecated and moved into the jQuery UI extension to jQuery. The docs you want are here:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete